# SQL: how to specify a date format on creating a table and fill it

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to save the date in format 'dd.mm.yyyy'. So I read there are different formats for a date in SQL (by the way I use Visual Studio and SQL Server).

I tried this code:

```
CREATE TABLE APP(
    ID   INT NOT NULL,
    DT DATE FORMAT 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    ADDRESS  NVARCHAR (100) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

But it returns the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'.

After that I want to use this code:

```
INSERT INTO APP (ID, DT)
VALUES ('1','22.12.2016')
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: DateTime is value type like an integer. you can not give it any formatting. You need to format while reading it.

Comment: Just store your dates using a date type, and worry about the visual formatting later using something like `CONVERT`.  _Don't_ store your dates as text.

Comment: Just a thought, but the example you give '12.22.2016' is not in the format that the erroneous table definition is giving 'dd.mm.yyyy' (there are only 12 months not 22). What do you actually want to supply in the insert statement USA format or German format?

Comment: @MartinBrown you are right! Thank you! It is German format, just miss clicked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to specify the format in the table definition as dates are stored in a binary format.

```
CREATE TABLE APP(
    ID   INT NOT NULL,
    DT DATE,
    ADDRESS  NVARCHAR (100) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

When you try to insert into that table however, the server will try to convert the string to a date before inserting it. This can be problematic as it is unable to tell if 12.11.2017 is the 12th of November or 11th of December. To figure this out it uses the localization settings of the user account that is performing the operation.

Often you will find that the account that is running the operation is set to USA format, month day then year (MDY), when what you want is day month year (DMY) format. One way to tell it what the sequence of the date's parts is to use the [DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) setting like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

INSERT INTO APP (ID, DT)
VALUES (1,'22.12.2016')
```

Another alternative is to cast the string to a date using the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) function and tell it what the date format is. The formats have [numeric codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) like 104 for German format Like this:

```
INSERT INTO APP (ID, DT)
VALUES (2,CONVERT(date,'22.12.2016',104))
```

Answer (score 5):

Dates are stored in an internal format.  Formats only make sense for input and output.

In your case you want the date in a German format (104), so you can use:

```
select convert(varchar(255), dt, 104)
```

If you like, you can include the formatted date as a separate column:

```
CREATE TABLE APP (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    DT DATE,
    ADDRESS  NVARCHAR(100),
    DT_FORMATTED AS (convert(varchar(255), dt, 104)),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

You can then refer to `dt_formatted` to get the string in the format you want.

Comment: Thank you for so fast answer! Can you please add some point: how can I add date as `INSERT INTO APP (ID, DT) VALUES ('1','22.12.2016')` ? Using German format

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql - You need to convert it to 104 according to the page

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
CREATE TABLE APP(
    ID   INT NOT NULL,
    DT DATE ,
    ADDRESS  NVARCHAR (100) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Its default setting is yyyy-MM-dd.

No, it's not. There is no formatting information at all associated with the field.

The value is not formatted by the database. It's returned only as a point in time. Formatting that value into its textual representation is done by the application that is getting the data from the database.

So, there is nothing that you can do in the database to change how the date value is formatted. You have to change that where the data is displayed.

Comment: What are you quoting from? E.g. "yyyy-MM-dd" is not anywhere on this page (incl. comments and deleted posts (there are none). Nor in any post revision.).

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored in an internal format.
Formats only make sense for input and output.

You can include the formatted date as a separate column:

SQL Server supports the date format. You have to use the below date format.

---

### With century (yyyy)  |  Standard       |    Input/Output

```
 103              |    British/French |  103 = dd/mm/yyyy



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post]
(
    [Id]       INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]     VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [RowNo]    INT  NULL,
    [ColNo]    INT  NULL,
    [Deadline] (CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), dt, 103)),  -- Include the formatted date as a separate column

    CONSTRAINT [PK_KtoCo]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(EID NUMBER(20),
ENAME VARCHAR2(20),
DT DATE,
SAL NUMBER(20));
```

INSERT INTO THE TABLE:

```
INSERT INTO EMP (EID,ENAME,DT,SAL) VALUES(01,'ABCDE','11.NOV.2011',10000);
```

O/P OF ABOVE TABLE:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP;
```

EID     ENAME       DT          SAL

01      ABCDE       11-DEC-11   10000